# Detecting disconnected Microsoft Access linked table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

The bottom line is that I want to handle network disconnection as gracefully as possible.

I have a Microsoft Access application that has "separated" the UI from the data using linked tables. So, there are two msaccess database files (one UI and the other data). Both of these databases are on the our internal network, and the UI links to the data using Linked Tables. It's a pretty standard setup.

There's only a single location in the code that I want this graceful disconnection logic (it's when a SQL UPDATE is performed). I thought it would be as simple as some error handling. However, **Microsoft Access sometimes pretends to succeed**!

Here's a window into my world:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Call CurrentDb.Execute("UPDATE [Thing] SET [Length]=5 WHERE [ID]=1;", dbFailOnError)
On Error GoTo 0

   ...(continued code)...

ErrorHandler:
    fSuccess = False
    Resume Next
```

I start up the application, unplug my network cable (no, wifi isn't on), but **sometimes the error handling never occurs**, even though it didn't actually update! To clarify, *when disconnected, I want this update to fail, and I want to detect it!*

I've been attempting to work around Access lying to me like this. The more I've tried, the more desperate I've become:

1. One of the first things I noticed is that **it will correctly and reliably fail if I step through with the debugger**. This doesn't help me, though.
2. I've tried checking **RecordCount** of the update operation, but when it pretends to succeed, it is truly set to 1!
3. I've tried doing a subsequent SELECT statement to see if UPDATE really happened. Access comes back with the correct results, though, even if I put a random number in the UPDATE.
4. I have looked through the Access objects (like CurrentDb and the TableDefs) looking for any reliable indication that it's working in "offline mode" or "cached mode". I cannot find any indicator. This would help me greatly.
5. The RecordCount of the linked table is always -1 whether connected or disconnected.
6. I have *disconnected and reconnected* the associated TableDef by mangling and fixing the "Connect" connection string. Access claims that it reconnected fine.

I'm don't understand behavior I'm seeing. Is MSAccess operating under some cache of the connected data? If so, why is it only working *sometimes*? And if they really do have some sophisticated offline cache mode, why is it not documented anywhere? Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to drink at work.

Comment: +1 for your final sentence. (However, the rest of the question is worthy of +1 as well.)

Comment: Are you using the  `dbFailOnError` parameter?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry it's not clear, I simplified the example because the full code is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I have come up with so far is to check whether or not I have network access to the underlying database file.

```
Public Function EnsureNetworkConnected() As Boolean

    Dim sDataPath As String
    sDataPath = GetDataPath

    Dim fFileExists As Boolean
    Dim objFileSystem As New FileSystemObject
    fFileExists = objFileSystem.FileExists(sDataPath)
    If Not fFileExists Then
        ' Huh.
    End If

    EnsureNetworkConnected = fFileExists

End Function
```

If the update statement "pretends" to succeed, I double-check it using this function. It's a flimsy hack.

If you have my problem and intend to use this solution, the **GetDataPath** function used gets the location of the linked tables through **CurrentDb.TableDefs**

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem exactly like you describe, but I do two things differently:

1. I always declare `Dim cdb As DAO.Database`, `Set cdb = CurrentDB`, and then do `cdb.Whatever`. There are times when doing `CurrentDB.Whatever` behaves differently.
2. I always do `cdb.Execute "SQL statement", dbFailOnError`. I think this might be particularly relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm already already doing both of these, but I cheated for simplicity of the example.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, as you suggested, the db engine performs the `UPDATE` against the cached version of your `[Thing]` table present in memory with the intention of writing it to disk later.  However, if that's what's going on, it seems like Access should throw an error later when it attempts to perform the disk write.

Honestly I don't understand why you're not getting an error.  I think it might be useful to try the `UPDATE` in a transaction and [use `dbForceOSFlush` with `CommitTrans`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835985.aspx).  At least it might force an error which your code could catch to know when you have that problem.

```vb
Dim strUpdate As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace

strUpdate = "UPDATE [Thing] SET [Length]=5 WHERE [ID]=1;"
Set ws = DBEngine(0)
Set db = CurrentDb
ws.BeginTrans
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
ws.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush
ws.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
```

Comment: This is a great idea. I wasn't aware of this flush idea. I will try this when I am able. At the moment, my hack of checking network access is currently in place and makes it hard to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread is a bit old but I'm now caught in the same situation as described and wanted to add my two pennies.

I added the "dbForceOSFlush" as suggested by HansUp above. Still I do not get an error when I remove my network cable (And turn of WiFi)

```
Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set wrk = DBEngine(0)
Set dbs = CurrentDb
wrk.BeginTrans
dbs.Execute "aJudges", dbFailOnError
wrk.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush
Debug.Print "AppendJudger " & Time()
TimerCounter = 0
```

Another observation is that when I pull the network, the first attempt to execute the query takes long time (Like 30 seconds) then after that all queries runs smoothly only that the connection is lost and consequently you lose any data when closing Access.